# How to sort a table?

Tags: smart-contract, table

I'm following this explanation https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cpp/v1.1.0/docs/multi-index-table-tutorial using v1.5.0 of the CDT.  Here's what I've got:

```
struct [[eosio::table]] order_struct {
    name cust;
    asset qty;
    uint32_t ts; 
    uint64_t primary_key() const {
        return ts; 
     }   
     uint64_t matches() const {
        return qty.symbol.code().raw();
     }
};  

typedef eosio::multi_index<
    name("orderbook"), 
    order_struct, 
    indexed_by<
        name("idxmatches"), 
        const_mem_fun<
            order_struct, uint64_t, &order_struct::matches
        >   
     >   
> orderbook;
```

after which I proceed to use the index as prescribed:

```
orderbook b(_self, _self.value);
auto m = b.get_index<name("idxmatches")>();

for (auto &o : m) {
    print(o.cust, " ", o.qty, " ", o.ts, "\n");
}
```

but this is what I get:

```
[(t,exchange)->t]: CONSOLE OUTPUT BEGIN ===================== 
alice 5.00000 NAVC 1549087727
bob 1.00000000 NAVG 1549088004
bob 1.00000000 NAVG 1549088036
alice 3.00000 NAVC 1549087912 
bob 7.00000000 NAVG 1549088304
alice 1.00000 NAVC 1549105457
[(t,exchange)->t]: CONSOLE OUTPUT END   =====================
```

**which is clearly not sorted.  what am I missing?**

p.s. the link includes a call to the EOSLIB_SERIALIZE macro.  I've tested behaviour with it but it doesn't help

p.p.s. another approach, which I picked up from [https://forum.toshitimes.com/t/advanced-eos-003-table-secondary-indexes/6329] also failed:

```
auto iter = m.lower_bound(NAVC.code().raw());
while (iter != m.end()) {
    print(iter->cust, " ", iter->qty, " ", iter->ts, "\n");
    iter++;
}
```

Comment: Feel free to hit up the EOS Dev telegram if you don't get a response: https://t.me/joinchat/Esi1OkPktgcFeJ3Lmlcrqg

Comment: thanks.  I'm in there.  it's a good channel.  I like to ask questions on the channel by writing here and then posting a link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  the code works as expected but I had to refresh (completely destroy and rebuild) my network.  it's something about EOS getting confused when the table definition changes